# Doctrine queryBuilder, return element in array 0

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

So, i have this query in my repository :

```
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select(array('a', 'COUNT(t.id) as counter'))
            ->from('MyProjectBundle:Account', 'a')
                ->leftjoin('a.tha', 'th')
                ->leftjoin('th.the', 't')
            ->where('t.is_good = ?1')
            ->groupby('a')
            ->orderby('counter', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(30)
            ->setParameters(array(1 => $is_good));
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

So, with this query, i have a list of account, order by `counter`. When i return the result of this query in json, i can see :

```
{    
    "myjson": [
        {
            "0": {
                "username": "blabla",
            },
            "counter": "2"
        }
        {
            "0": {
                "username": "aeiouy",
            },
            "counter": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see the `"0"` for each element in my json.. How can i remove these 0 ? I want something like :

```
{    
    "myjson": [
        {
            "username": "blabla",                
            "counter": "2"
        },
        {
            "username": "aeiouy",
            "counter": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change it to

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select(array('a.username', 'COUNT(t.id) as counter'))
        ->from('MyProjectBundle:Account', 'a')
            ->leftjoin('a.tha', 'th')
            ->leftjoin('th.the', 't')
        ->where('t.is_good = ?1')
        ->groupby('a')
        ->orderby('counter', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(30)
        ->setParameters(array(1 => $is_good));
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```